# How to deal with missing survival times using Cox PH model (R)?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, missing-data

I have been working with a dataset that I would like to analyze using the Cox PH model in R. The data I have includes:

- a start measurement year
- an estimated mortality year
- survival time that is the difference of these two
- multiple complete case covariates (no NAs)

The problem I cannot seem to find an answer to is **how do I deal with individuals who have survived beyond the study period (survival time = NA)?** I am familiar with the concept of censoring, however I do not believe this is appropriate in this case - let me explain why.

I have data from 3 different states: Nevada, Colorado, and Arizona. Each of these contain approximately 120-250 individuals who experienced the desired event (in this case mortality) and 2000-4000 individuals who did not (survival time is listed as NA). Censoring this many individuals gives drastically different results, as expected. However, filling the NA's with a survival time equal to the study period also seems inappropriate - as I am assuming their death upon completion of the study. The inclusion of NAs in the Cox PH model removes these observations due to missingness, therefore censoring them automatically.

How should I approach this issue? Pseudo-filling survival time is likely affecting my analysis. Is it actually appropriate to censor this many observations? Is there a way I can correct this?

Thank you for your time, and please let me know if further clarification is needed - this is my first time making a forum post.

Comment: Censoring seems to be the right approach here. It seems like "administrative" censoring, i.e., you can't wait until every event has happened.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Michael! Maybe I am misunderstanding the concept of censoring. Is it not inappropriate to exclude this many observations?

Comment: Censoring means setting the end time to the "end of observation date" and then setting the event flag to 0. You don't remove any observation. The response consists of a (time, event) tuple.

Comment: I think your edits provided clarity that I am doing it correctly, thank you for your clarification.

Comment: Agree with @MichaelM. This is exactly what censoring is for. They are censored in the sense that "the event happened/will happen after the conclusion of the study", and they should certainly be included in the analysis

Answer (score 1):

Converting comments into an answer. As @MichaelM said:

> Censoring means setting the end time to the "end of observation date" and then setting the event flag to 0. You don't remove any observation. The response consists of a (time, event) tuple.

In this situation, for an individual who hadn't yet experienced the event, you would set `time` to be the duration of the corresponding observation period, but `event` would be set to 0, indicating a right-censored event time (instead of to 1, which marks observed event times). Particularly with this "administrative censoring" at the end of a study period there is no problem with a high fraction of censored cases, provided that there are enough events during the study period.